# What charts do I need flying VFR between KPRC and KLAS?

Tags: usa, flight-planning

Some friends and I are going to fly up to Vegas from college to watch the Red Bull air races in a few weeks.  And after looking at the charts, I realized I am in a pretty unique situation.

The Phoenix sectional ends just short of Vegas - so normally I would buy a Vegas sectional.  However, the KLAS TAC extends just into the Phoenix sectional.

Should I buy the Vegas sectional as well, or can I just use the KLAS TAC once the Phoenix sectional ends?

[image]

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use paper charts? There are many apps available for tablets that provide the charts for free, which is a lot more practical in many cases, although of course you may still like to have paper as a backup.

Comment: Unfortunately I do have to use paper, I would love to use a tablet though... just not in the cards right now.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. Then as voretaq7 suggested I would take the TAC because it provides more detail.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand correctly, your question is "can I substitute a TAC for a sectional on a cross-country flight?" However, assuming that you're flying under part 91, there is no legal requirement to have any charts on board at all. [91.503](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?node=14:2.0.1.3.10#se14.2.91_1503) does require them, but only for large and turbine aircraft, and the FAA [has stated](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgAdvisoryCircular.nsf/0/EB15B0C685650A0486257321006B3B8C?OpenDocument) that electronic charts are allowed instead of paper.

There are a few places where it is required to carry a chart in the aircraft, per the Special Flight Rules Area regulations in [14 CFR 93](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=db6d462234c1e54c0fb044504e28fc56&mc=true&node=pt14.2.93&rgn=div5). Some examples are:

- Near Los Angeles International Airport ([93.95(c)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=db6d462234c1e54c0fb044504e28fc56&mc=true&node=pt14.2.93&rgn=div5#se14.2.93_195))
- The Hudson and East River Exclusions in New York City ([93.351(d)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=db6d462234c1e54c0fb044504e28fc56&mc=true&node=pt14.2.93&rgn=div5#se14.2.93_1351))

So unless 91.503 or one of the part 93 rules applies to your flight, legally you can carry whatever paper, electronic or hand-drawn charts you like - or none at all - although if you bust restricted airspace and the FAA come after you, not having charts on board may not look good. (Of course, if you do have them then the implication would be that you didn't use them or don't know how to read them, which isn't good either.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I do understand that I "don't need charts" but I was looking for 'insight' from a more experienced pilot than myself - and what they would do in the same situation.

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy Well, for what it's worth, I use Garmin Pilot on two separate portable devices for both VFR and IFR, with no paper backup, which is in addition to whatever is actually in the aircraft: either G1000 or G430. I feel comfortable that that gives me enough redundancy and I don't miss paper at all, but others may feel differently; 'insight' and 'opinion' are tough to separate.

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy Like Pondlife I just use an electronic flight bag (in my case, Foreflight on my iPad, and my iPhone as a backup). If you want to carry paper charts the TAC is certainly adequate if it covers your intended route/area of flight and you can use it as you describe in the question (in fact I would do this simply because the scale on the TAC provides more detail - particularly if you're not familiar with the Vegas airspace/landmarks).

Comment: @Pondlife I believe the DC SVFR area as well as the NYC Bravo/VFR Corridor require you to have charts on board similar to LA

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the pointer! I updated my answer: NYC is another good example, but I didn't see any requirements for the DC area. Maybe it's in a NOTAM or somewhere else.

Comment: @Pondlife It looks like i was mistaken I also cant find anything that requires you to have the chart on board for the DC SFRA

Comment: @Pondlife "Near LA International..." is really just when flying the SFRA  route from Santa Monica, over LAX, and to the other side, or vice versa. ForeFlight has the info in the LA TAC Supplement, and you can zoom in on the map page to get the TAC info, so you don’t need paper charts.